# 220V relay + ESP32 + aquarium heater

Tags: relay, heater

I am using an ESP32 (any microcontroller will be the same) to turn on/off an aquarium heater with a 220V relay (rated at 10A, with an octocoupler driven by a GPIO pin on Arduino, it's a small PCB that came from e-Bay.)  The relay is a mechanical type.

The board looks like this:

[image]

<sub>Source: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1aXS2B8mWBuNkSndVq6AsApXaS/5-v-1-Un-Canal-Module-de-Relais-Bas-Niveau-pour-Contr-le-D-appareils-M.jpg</sub>

The heater is rated @ 500W.

Sometimes when the relay kicks in, the home safety switch kicks in, and shuts down the power in the house.

This doesn't always happen.

I have double checked the wiring, and everything seems correct.  I also tried with an electric bulb (a standard socket bulb paired with a 9w led bulb, I don't have any old type bulb) and with 10-15 simulations it never happened. With heater it happens every 5-6 times.

My quess is that that relay + high power device doesn't work well.

I read that an RC snubber should help in this case, putting it in parallel with the socket driven by the relay.

Is that correct?

Can also someone explain me why this happens, just to better understand the cause?

[image]

I add a little schema on how it's wired all togheter, the L/N mean live/neutral, i can't know what got plugged into the wall (i can test it, but i can't guarantee someone doesn't plug/unplug it).   the heater have 2 pin, not connected to GND, it's a standard glass aquarium heater, sealed with resistor inside the glass pipe like this one

https://www.acquariomania.net/web/image/product.template/11829/image

Comment: Can you post what heater you are using, and the current rating of the switch that is kicking in? You are possibly drawing more current than (or close to) what your house wiring/switch was designed to provide. Could be that the heater draws more current when it is cold. You can either replace the heater with a lower power one, replace the wiring in your house, or find another outlet on another circuit with a higher rating.

Comment: "home safety switch" sounds more like an earth leakage breaker than an overcurrent breaker

Comment: You don't say what kind of plug the heater has and how you have connected the heater. Is the heater grounded? Do you provide ground to it? Do you switch the live (should be fine) or neutral (slightly dangerous)? Do you know if it is really live that is switched? Which country, do you have polarized or non-polarized plugs?

Comment: heater have 2 pin, 10A italian plug, no ground provided. Since it's a power socks, no idea if it's live or neutral that get switched, depend on how the relay got connected to main line, that depend on how the plug got inserted on the wall, if the maid come and take it of and on, it can change :)  i will add a drawing schema to main post

Answer (score 1):

Is this an old metal-cased aquarium heater? It's possible that the insulation is breaking down between the heater element and its metal case leading to your RCD/GFCI tripping. This is a characteristic failure mode for mineral insulated heaters.

You can carry out a quick check with an ordinary multimeter.  With the heater completely disconnected from the mains supply measure the resistance between either heater connection and the metal case. If it's less than 0.5 MΩ you need a new heater. If it's more than 0.5 MΩ it's not in the clear yet as these heaters need to be tested at twice their operating voltage (500V for you) with a proper insulation tester to be safe.

As you are building projects mixing mains voltage with water it would be worth you getting a cheap insulation tester of your own ([like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/KKmoon-Digital-Insulation-Resistance-Megohmmeter/dp/B078SLXBCP/)). Failing that you might find an electrician or electrical installers who would be prepared to check your heater with an insulation tester.

Comment: many thanks for your suggestion. The heater pipe (the container that have the resistors inside) it's made with glass, i did the test with multimeter and it report 0., the test have to be done from the plug to the body right? i guess that since it's not th emetal type but glass type it's normal that's 0

Comment: @user3804873 Having a glass heater eliminates one easy-to-find problem! If you are powering this all via a 3 pin plug you can check the insulation by unplugging the supply. Connect the phase and neutral pins together and measure the resistance from the connected pins to the earth pin/contact. If your opto-isolation arrangements aren't up to scratch doing this with a 500V insulation tester may destroy the electronics but it will find any earth leakage.